# My .emacs.el file is not loading, how can I get it to load?

Tags: emacs

I've used emacs for years, and on a Windows system.  I downloaded emacs from http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/windows/ and unzipped it locally.

I copied my .emacs file into `%USERPROFILE%\.emacs` and started emacs.

My .emacs file was not loading.  I added

```
(debug)
```

As the first line of the `.emacs.el` file and the emacs debugger did not start so I know the file was not loaded.

I searched for other questions like this but didn't find this question asked.

Comment: Have a look at [(emacs) Windows HOME](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Windows-HOME.html)

Comment: I'm find with this being a duplicate and I added my answer to the other question.  My question and the other one are two sides of the same coin.  **I knew where my .emacs file was but didn't know why it was loading**, the other question **doesn't know where the .emacs file is and wants to know where it is loaded from.**